# How to not showing next slide when last slide is reached with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm very new coding with JQuery.

What I want to do is prevent showing next slide (that becomes first slide of the slideshow) when last slide is reached (as in this carousel: [link to carousel](https://www.asla.org/sustainablelandscapes/index.html)). The only thing I did is to prevent showing previous/next button (".owl-prev/.owl-next" in my JQuery) for first/last slide adding a css class. I tried to hide next slide when last slide reached but not working. Anyone could help me?

Following JQuery actually working to hide buttons, css class to hide buttons and html carousel:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".owl-carousel").on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel refreshed.owl.carousel', function (event) {
if (!event.namespace) return;
var carousel = event.relatedTarget,
    element = event.target,
    current = carousel.current();
$('.owl-next', element).toggleClass('disabled', current === carousel.maximum());
$('.owl-prev', element).toggleClass('disabled', current === carousel.minimum());
});
```

```css
.owl-nav .owl-prev.disabled,
.owl-nav .owl-next.disabled {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
<div class="owl-stage-outer">
<div class="owl-stage">
<div class="dt-owl-item cloned">
<div class="dt-owl-item cloned">
<div class="dt-owl-item">
<div class="dt-owl-item">
<div class="dt-owl-item active">
<div class="dt-owl-item cloned">
<div class="dt-owl-item cloned">
```

And this is JQuery to prevent showing slide not working:

```
if (current === carousel.maximum()){
   $(".dt-owl-item").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the "loop" property off from your carousel?

Docs: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

***Update:***

I see, then you could try something like this to update its settings:

```
var $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
var owl = $carousel.data();
owl["owl.carousel"].options.loop = false;
owl["owl.carousel"].refresh();
```

Dunno if it's the best way to fix it, but it worked for me.

Comment: I can't use loop property as none of owl carousel events, properties and classes works for me. Note that I use a wordpress plugin included in The 7 Theme, that's why I'm searching for JQuery event that doesn't need to owl carousel own events. Thank you for your help

Comment: I've updated my answer to adapt to your situation, let me know if it helps.

Comment: still not working, I also tried: owl["owl.carousel"].rotate = false; and owl["owl.carousel"].infinite = false; but neither of them works. 
I had the only visible result using this function: 
if (current === carousel.maximum()){
    var $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
    var owl = $carousel.data();
    owl["owl.carousel"].options.loop=false;
    owl["owl.carousel"].refresh();
  }

but using it, I have this console error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". Any idea fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: That's weird, could you try triggering the refresh event like this:?

$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').options.loop = false;

$('.owl-carousel').trigger( 'refresh.owl.carousel' );

Maybe try with another setting (like *options.nav*) instead of options.loop to check if something changes on your carousel.

Comment: None of them working.
Using both:
I have two consol errors:
1) Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
2) Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)carousel\.(?:.*\.|)owl(\.|$)/: Stack overflow.
Really do not know why

Comment: Last chance, try triggering the owl carousel refresh method instead of the jquery:
$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').options.loop = false;
$('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

If not, we might need a jsfiddle to try and find the solution..
BTW, what version of owl carousel are you using?

Comment: using last, I got this console error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. About owl carousel version, I really don't know as it's a theme plugin and I tried to use both owl carousel 1 and owl carousel 2 functions, but neither of them works. On link https://ibb.co/d4wo7d, you can find the plugin image, in its options there no change to set loop false. If JSfiddle is needed, i'll work on it.

Comment: At this point I would need more info (like the wordpress plugin used and its version, were are you trying to run the jQuery code)  You could also check what Owl Carousel version are you using from your developer tools,  it might help

Comment: I've found solution using another plugin (advanced carousel in the 7 theme) with infinite loop built-in, and I assigned this css class .slick-disabled {
   display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
} to disable arrow when first/last slide reached.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do it like:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
```

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:false,
margin:10,
nav:false })
```

Notice the loop:false property and you won't have to subscribe to different events of carousel.

Comment: Nothing happen with your JQuery. Note that I use a wordpress plugin included in The 7 Theme and any .owlCarousel events doesn't work for me. That's why I'm searching for JQuery event that doesn't need to owl carousel own events. Could be useful your JQuery "translated" to Javascript without owl carousel own events. Thanks!